# Use shift in pd.NamedAgg groupby in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

I find it very convenient to use `pd.NamedAgg` in order to give names to columns after aggregation, but I don't know how to do other aggregate functions like `shift`. The code bellow doesn't work because of the 3rd aggregation.

```
df.groupby(["ID", "Day", "hour"]).agg(
    profit_avg=pd.NamedAgg(column='profit', aggfunc='mean'),
    volume_max=pd.NamedAgg(column='volume', aggfunc='max'),
    pn_price_shift=pd.NamedAgg(column='price', aggfunc='shift')
    )
```

I get this error:

```
NotImplementedError: Can only union MultiIndex with MultiIndex or Index of tuples, try
mi.to_flat_index().union(other) instead.
```

Comment: `groupby_agg` is used to aggregate values (map and reduce). `shift` function doesn't reduce but it's like `transform`?